# When updating an array in a JavaScript object the prototype is updated. Why?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Kind of strange thing is happening with my code. What I observe is something like this:

```
var prototype = {
    property : "",
    array : []
}

var objectArray = [];

function myFunction {
    objectArray[0] = Object.create(prototype);
    objectArray[1] = Object.create(prototype);

    objectArray[0].property = "Hello 1";
    objectArray[0].array.push("Hello 1");
    objectArray[1].property = "Hello 2";
    objectArray[1].array.push("Hello 2");

    // At this point when running the program I get:
    // objectArray[0].property == "Hello 1"
    // objectArray[1].property == "Hello 2";
    // objectArray[1].array == objectArray[1].array == prototype.array
    // == ["Hello 1", "Hello 2"]
}
```

What I want, and expected, was two separate arrays for the two objects. What am I missing here?

Comment: Where would the separate array be created? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, objects are copied by reference, so both `objectArray` objects are simply references to the same object ( `prototype` ). You need to clone the object or create instances using the `new` keyword and a constructor to create separate objects.

Example on how to do it using the `new` keyword:

```
var prototype = function() {
    this.property = "";
    this.array = [];
};

objectArray[0] = new prototype();
objectArray[1] = new prototype();
```

You can also do:

```
var prototypeFactory = function() {
    return {
        property: "",
        array: []
    };
};

objectArray[0] = prototypeFactory();
objectArray[1] = prototypeFactory();
```

Comment: Objects technically aren't *copied by reference*. They're always copying values; an object's *value* is a reference.

Comment: @alex how do you mean? Isn’t that just semantics? `a={};b=a;b.foo='bar';alert(a.foo);`

Comment: What @alex means is (I think), if it were a real reference, you could assign to it, but you can't: `a={}; b=a; b={foo:'bar'}; console.log(a);` (`a` is still `{}`, not `{foo:'bar'}`). So it's a "reference value", not an actual reference.

Comment: *"...so both `objectArray` objects are simply references to the same object ( `prototype` )"*. This isn't right. It makes it sound as though `objectArray[0]` and `[1]` are actually references to the `prototype` object, which isn't the case. *"You need to clone the object or create instances using the `new` keyword and a constructor to create separate objects."* That's already what's happening. `Object.create` makes new instances, just like a constructor would.

Comment: @bfavaretto sorry, I misread your example. I get your point now :)

Comment: @user1689607 I was under the impression that `Object.create` takes an object as argument and applies that as it’s own prototype. So the prototype object will be inherited through the newly created object, thus making the prototype *values* references?

Comment: @David: `Object.create` makes a new empty object, that has the first argument passed as its `[[Prototype]]`. So it's just like invoking a constructor function, but without the constructor. So `var foo = new Foo();` and `var foo = Object.create(Foo.prototype);` are equivalent, assuming the `Foo` constructor doesn't actually modify the new object. So yes, you do *have* a reference to the `prototype` object through the typical prototypal inheritance mechanism, but it's quite different to say that `objectArray[0]` *is* a reference to `prototype`. It would be correct to say it *inherits* from it.

Comment: ...should be more like: *"...so both `objectArray` objects inherit from the same object ( `prototype` )."*

Answer (score 0):

The `prototype` object exists the same as the `[[Prototype]]` for each object. They don't get a fresh copy when you use `Object.create()`.

You'd need to use assignment, which never walks the prototype chain.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you aren't asking yourself "why does it work for `property`, but not for `array`?". The fact is, it doesn't work for `property` either, JavaScript is fooling you.

When objects share the same prototype, one must consider that:

- All properties of the prototype are shared by the objects that inherit from that prototype.
- **You cannot assign to properties of the prototype, only read them** (unless it's an accessor property, but let's keep that aside).

So what's actually happening here:

```
objectArray[0].property = "Hello 1";
objectArray[1].property = "Hello 2";
```

is that a new **own** property called "property" is being created on each object, while `prototype.property` remains untouched. The `array` property is behaving differently because you're not assigning to it, you're accessing `prototype.array` and calling the `push` method on it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that `Object.create()` isn't yet standardized, and won't work in IE8 or FF3.6.  A simple work-around to clone an object is to use the JSON object:

```
function clone(obj) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is standardized.

Comment: Standardized means widely implemented in browsers?

Comment: This is not the same as `Object.create`, it will always return an object that inherits directly from `Object.prototype`. And it won't work if any property of the object is a function. The workaround for browsers that don't support `Object.create` is [Crockford's `object` function](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html). This question isn't about cloning, but inheritance.

Comment: "Won't work in IE8 or FF3.6" means browser implementation.  And the original question makes absolutely no mention of inheritance.